# Prolog - How to separate atoms from expression involving predicates?

Tags: prolog

If I’ve an expression:

```
x + y * (-z)
```

How to I separate them to form a list of `[x,y,z]`?

My idea:

```
split2(X, [X]) :-
    X \= +(_,_),
   *(_,_),
   -(_).

split2(X + Y, [H|T]) :- 
    split2(X,[H]), 
    split2(Y, T).
```

(Repeat for * and -).

Somehow it only works for simple case(involving 2 terms or only one predicate), but not complicated one.

Can someone tells me what’s wrong with my idea?

Comment: `x + y * (-z)` is not a predicate.

Answer (score 2):

Your predicates are pretty mixed up. For starters, you're using `X \= _+_` to prevent the other rule from matching; instead you should use `atomic(X)`. You're then saying `_*_, -_` which is not clearly saying anything in particular except that certain anonymous variables... exist? Anyway, the rest of the first clause is erroneous for one reason or another.

Your second clause is off to a decent start, but I think you are avoiding a use of `append/3` here for no particular reason. In the head, you are expecting `H` to be an atom, but then with the first term in the body you're forcing `H` to be a singleton list. What if `X = a*b`? You'd expect `split2(a*b,[a,b])` to unify.

You're not far from where you need to be though. This is probably your general pattern:

```
split2(X, [X]) :- atomic(X).
split2(-X, Result) :- split2(X, Result).
split2(X+Y, Result) :-
    split2(X, XVars),
    split2(Y, YVars),
    append(XVars, YVars, Result).
```

Continue the pattern for your other operators.

Answer (score 2):

Follows a solution using DCGs that doesn't require a grammar rule per arithmetic operator and that takes full advantage of first-argument indexing (thus avoiding spurious choice-points or ugly cuts in the grammar rules):

```
split(Expression, Atomics) :-
    Expression =.. [Functor| Args],
    phrase(split_atomics(Args, Functor), Atomics).

split_atomics([], Atomic) -->
    [Atomic].
split_atomics([Head| Tail], _) -->
    split_list([Head| Tail]).

split_list([]) -->
    [].
split_list([Head| Tail]) -->
    {Head =.. [Functor| Args]},
    split_atomics(Args, Functor),
    split_list(Tail).
```

Sample calls:

```
| ?- split((x + y * (-z)), Atomics).

Atomics = [x, y, z]
yes

| ?- split((x + 3 * (-2)), Atomics).

Atomics = [x, 3, -2]
yes
```

Comment: Great, I did not know that `?- a =.. L.` happily answers `L = [a].`

Comment: @User9213 E.g. `3.14 =.. L` and `42 =.. L` are also valid standard Prolog goals.

Comment: Cleanest solution, since `split(X, Xs)` produces an instantiation error and not (incorrect) silent failure.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone tells me what's wrong with my idea?

What you are doing is too complicated, that's what's wrong. If you really have as input a valid compound term, and what you need to get out of it is a list of the atomic sub-terms, then, here is what you might want to try:

```
expression_atoms(E) -->
    {   compound(E),
        E =.. [_Name|Args]
    },
    !,
    expression_list_atoms(Args).
expression_atoms(E) -->
    {   atomic(E)
    },
    !,
    [E].

expression_list_atoms([E|Es]) -->
    expression_atoms(E),
    expression_list_atoms(Es).
expression_list_atoms([]) --> [].
```

(Ninja edit: see the [solution by Paulo Moura](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54573391/10721357) for a cleaner implementation of the same idea.)

The only reason why this is a DCG and not a normal predicate is that I am too lazy to figure out how to do the appends properly.

Here is a small test:

```
?- X = x + y * (-z).
X = x+y* -z.

?- X = x + y * (-z), write_canonical(X).
+(x,*(y,-(z)))
X = x+y* -z.

?- X = x + y * (-z), write_canonical(X), phrase(expression_atoms(X), Atoms).
+(x,*(y,-(z)))
X = x+y* -z,
Atoms = [x, y, z].
```

In the last query, you can see the atoms extracted from the expression.

As you see, this solution doesn't care about the names of the compound terms. This happens in line 3 of the listing:

```
E =.. [_Name|Args]
```

So you can throw anything at it and it will still "work":

```
?- phrase(expression_atoms(
    the(naked, truth(about(our(waitresses))), is(that(they(only(flirt, with, you))), to(get(a(better(tip('!')))))))),
    Atoms).
Atoms = [naked, waitresses, flirt, with, you, !].
```

If you want this to fail for anything else but a predefined list of operators with a given arity, then you'd have to put a bit more code in there.